# SQL injections from remote file

Tags: php, mysql, security, code-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I have a file, "submit.php", which writes a series of values submitted from a previous form in "choose-product.php" to a MySQL database. I've used `mysql_real_escape_string` as suggested in a previous question here, but I've noticed that if I upload my "choose-product.php" file to a separate server and change the opening of the form to

```
<form name="form" id="form" action="http://www.myserver.com/submit.php" method="post">
```

this will **also** write a series of values to the database. Obviously this is very bad! Now, I know there will be a way to rectify this, but as this is my first time writing such code, I'm a bit stumped.

Here's the full code for `submit.php`:

```
<?php
include("db.php");

function random_string() {
    $character_set_array = array();
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 7, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 3, 'characters' => '0123456789');
    $character_set_array[] = array('count' => 1, 'characters' => '!@#$*&:');
    $temp_array = array();
    foreach ($character_set_array as $character_set) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < $character_set['count']; $i++) {
            $temp_array[] = $character_set['characters'][rand(0, strlen($character_set['characters']) - 1)];
        }
    }
    shuffle($temp_array);
    return implode('', $temp_array);
}

$key = random_string();


if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    $productid = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['productid']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO sales VALUES('','$productid','$key',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'','active')");
    echo "
    <form action='XYZ' id='BB_BuyButtonForm' method='post' name='BB_BuyButtonForm' target='_top'>
        <input name='item_name_1' type='hidden' value='Test item 1'/>
        <input name='item_description_1' type='hidden' value='Testing item sales'/>
        <input name='item_quantity_1' type='hidden' value='1'/>
        <input name='item_price_1' type='hidden' value='0.5'/>
        <input name='item_currency_1' type='hidden' value='GBP'/>
        <input name='shopping-cart.items.item-1.digital-content.url' type='hidden' value='http://www.XYZ.com/download.php?key=$key'/>
        <input name='_charset_' type='hidden' value='utf-8'/>
        <input alt='' src='XYZ' type='image'/>
    </form>
    ";
}
?>
```

Comment: The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which have important advantages, such as support for prepared statements. Prepared statement parameters are the modern way to prevent injection, as they are invulnerable to it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, this is how I am understanding your question: When you upload your code to a different server, that server is able to add/update rows in your database. You want to know this is and how to stop the other server from saving to your database?

Comment: How is it very bad?  If the data comes from the script on your server or from a form hosted on a different server, the end result is still the same.  Provided all input is properly validated then there's no issue with where the submitting form is hosted.

Comment: @GordonM - the form submits information to the database and creates a secret key, which is included as a 'hidden' form input before the user is directed to Google Checkout for payment. I'm using javascript to send the information to submit.php without leaving choose-product.php (so the workings of submit.php aren't visible). But if someone else were to copy the choose-product.php (minus the javascript), they'd be redirected to www.myserver.com/submit.php. A right click would reveal the hidden key, and they'd be able to bypass the sales process altogether. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: @Martin: from looking at the source for your question, you use HTML non-[semantically](http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/5-site-structure/2-semantic-markup.html). Avoid presentational elements (such as `<b>`) and replace non-semantic element use with semantic elements (e.g. use `<p>` instead of [`<br/>`](http://brainstormsandraves.com/articles/semantics/structure/#br)). You should also read over the Markdown syntax help, accessible via the orange question mark in the post editor.

Comment: ...  For readability's sake, please pick and apply an [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) when writing code. Any proper code editor/IDE will automatically indent code for you.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to the HTTP protocol.

http://www.myserver.com/submit.php can be called by anyone, at any time. The form that calls in can be on any other web page. Or the user may not actually call it from a form at all, but may use a command line tool to submit data. This tool could claim to be a web browser and you would not know.

I'm guessing from your Q:

Are you relying on choose-product.php to provide some kind of security for submit.php?

You can't.

You must do all checks for security on submit.php, even if you've just done them for choose-product.php 5 seconds ago.

Comment: Ah, just seen your comment. Things are suddenly more complex and unclear. (Using JS does not make the workings of submit.php invisible btw.) Um, sorry to be harsh, but you say this is the first time you have coded this and I think you need to get a professional programmer, especially on something as important as a checkout process.

Comment: Not exactly, @James. choose-product.php: the user chooses the product they wish to purchase. On clicking 'Buy now', the form the product ID to submit.php, which writes a secret key alongside it. The user doesn't leave choose-product.php because I'm using JavaScript to run through submit.php without leave the page. The 'Buy now' button changes to a 'Checkout' button, which take the user to Google Checkout. On completion of payment, that secret code created earlier is included in a link to download the product. Once downloaded, the secret code is erased.

Comment: Hi James. That's not harsh at all. I appreciate the advice. I'm not a total novice, and I'm determined to learn (although I'm starting to think an experienced programmer might be easier...!)

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to take a step back and look at the whole process, as I'm not sure of some of the reasoning. If you don't want to get a pro to do it all at least get them to go thru the design with you first and look at the finished code after. I'm all for learning - I would just encourage you to do it on something not involving money :-)

Comment: Why do you not simply create the secret key based upon the return value you receive from google checkout.
Or if you really have/want to create it before the checkout, store it in a session rather than a hidden form field.

Comment: How do you mean @Erik (based upon the return value...)? If you have an idea for a better solution, trust me - I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Having not worked with google checkout before, but assuming it works just like any other payment gateway (paypal?) you send the details of what the buyer is purchasing to google checkout.
When the buyer has paid for the product they are returned to your website, and with that, google checkout sends information about the payment, a status update if you will, telling you if the payment was completed or not

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an injection issue. Your php script has to have, somewhere, the location, username, and password for your database. Unless your database is configured specifically to not allow it, anyone with that info (such as your script here) can use it to make changes.

It is common, and easy, to restrict access to you local host. I am googling how to do that now.

Comment: Um, your PHP script having the username/password for DB != "anyone can use that information to make changes." If your server is configured properly no-one else should see that info. (Altho you are correct to state that MySQL can be setup to only allow connections from localhost and that is a sensible security precaution.)

Comment: Edited to make my statement more clear: the php script can change the database because IT as access to the user, db, pass.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you think that if a PHP script has a host/username/password for a DB then anyone in the world can find out what that h/u/p is and then use them to access the MySQL server directly? Cos that's what I'm taking from your answer.

Comment: I added "anyone with that info (such as your script here) can use it" to make it clear that I'm saying the script has the info and thus can use it. I'm not saying that anyone can get it - I'm saying he copied it along with the script (unless i'm misunderstanding his post)

Comment: I finally see what you mean. He copied choose-product.php which I assume doesn't have the DB access in. Also the stuff about changing URL implies this is not the problem. But we can't really tell, Q is vague.

Comment: Yeah. I read it and interpreted it as "I copied my project from server a to server b, and server b can edit my DB". I even asked in the comments to make sure :)